# how to include yaml file in another yaml and overwrite some variable in Bamboo deployment YAML

Tags: yaml, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I'm writing bamboo deployment yaml and wants to include another yaml for common functionality and overwrite some of specific variables. eg- I have following yaml But When Import them in Bamboo , it gives me error-

```
Bamboo YAML import failed: Invalid format of the YAML file: while constructing a mapping in 'reader', line 21, column 3: <<: *map
 expected a mapping or list of mappings for merging, 
but found scalar
 in 'reader', line 17, column 7:    DEV: &map
```

Please can any one explains what I'm doing wrong here-

```
#bamboo.yaml
---
version: 2
deployment:
  name: Deploy test
  source-plan: "TEST2"

release-naming:
  next-version-name: release-${bamboo.buildNumber}
  applies-to-branches: false

environments:
  - TEST
  - DEV 
  

DEV: &map
  !include 'deployment/another.yaml'
    
TEST:
  <<: *map
  variables:
    ENV:  test
---
#another.yaml looks like as follows-

triggers:
  - build-success
tasks:
- clean
- script:
    - echo "I’m here"
final-tasks: []
variables: 
  ENV: dev
requirements: []
notifications: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put an include there, it needs to be mapped to an element, we use it like this:

```
Dev: &dev-env
  tasks: !include "template/tasks-1.yaml"
  final-tasks: !include "template/tasks-final.yaml"
  variables:
    branch: master
    namespace: prod
    application: xyz
    validate.timeout: 900
  triggers:
    - build-success
QA:
  <<: *dev-env
  variables:
    branch: qa
    application: xyz
    namespace: qa
    validate.timeout: 900
  triggers: []
```

Answer (score 1):

like leadjunk mentioned you can add a !include "file" statement
be aware you cant use a include on highlevel
more information can be found here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/how-to-use-bamboo-specs-include-YAML/qaq-p/1112625